# Multiprocessing pickle.load() :: EOFError - Ran out of input

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, multiprocessing, pickle

I have an issue where I am running a CPU heavy multiprocessing task that reads and writes to one pickle file to avoid running calculations on the same input.

I have a queue going for the file writing function [not shown], but not for the reading function. Most of the time, when I run the multiprocess, I receive an "EOFError - ran out of input" exception. My best guess is that two processes are trying to read the file (via pickle_read) at the same time.

```
def pickle_read(category):
    with open("completed_search.txt", "rb") as pickle_set:
        try:
            return pickle.load(pickle_set)[category]
        except EOFError as e:
            handle_error(e)


if reg in pickle_read('region'):
    continue
```

How could I queue a process to allow for synchronous reads while satisfying the conditional (i.e. not return a NoneType)?